# HTML Import webcomponents polyfill not working in firefox

Tags: web-component, polyfills, custom-element, html-imports

I am trying webcomponents in a sample app. Since some of the specs are not included in some browsers, i tried using polyfill for those. In Mozilla firefox, i tried by enabling the key dom.webcomponents.enabled and adding some polyfills (that are not in browser). I have used HTML Import polyfill from webcomponents.js polyfill.

Still HTMLImport is not working in firefox, internet explorer (even with polyfill). (https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs)

I also tried customElements v1 polyfill, not working in internet explorer and firefox. (https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements)

Has anybody succeeded in including HTMLimports polyfill with customElements V1 polyfill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use, in Firefox, Custom Elements v1 with HTML Imports:

1. **Do not** activate Firefox flags as the implementation is outdated.
2. Install **webcomponentsjs** (with bower for example), and include in your main file only `htmlimports.min.js` file.
3. Install **custom-elements** (from your link) and include in your main file `custom-elements.min.js`.

You main page should look like this:

```
<head>
   <script src="htmlimports.min.js"></script>
   <script src="custom-elements.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="import" href="your-components.html">
</head>
<body>
    <your-component></your-component>
```

*NB:* for step 3, you can also use [document-register-element](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element).

---

You cannot use Custom Elements v1 `class` syntax with Internet Explorer directly because `class` is not implemented. You'll need first to transform the source code with a transpiler like Babel.

Alternately, use a modern version (Edge), or use the `prototype` syntax.

Comment: I do not see how downloading webcomponentsjs is connected to including *only* `htmlimports.min.js`. When I inspect the package, I don't see any such file?

Comment: @Peak the version and content of the linked package have evolved since the time the answer was posted. Now you'd better follow this new post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51939275/4600982