# Web component - polyfill not working on firefox and safari

Tags: web-component, polyfills

i have a simple index.html with an import of a component, exaclty [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091849/web-component-vanilla-no-polymer-how-to-load-template-content).
On Chrome works fine, but on others browser (i tried firefox and safari) not, it shows only the index.html content, not the template content of the component. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738748/html-import-webcomponents-polyfill-not-working-in-firefox) and it seems like my situation, but this solution doesn't work for me.

EDIT: imports are correct (from IDE, if I command+click on links, I can go to the .js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `document.currentScript` doesn't work with polyfill.

You should use instead :

```
( document._currentScript || document.currentScript )
```

**Update**: Or you can use the [new version of HTML Imports polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports), that makes `document.currentScript` work as expected.

Comment: Because I went the same route as you... I can guess your next qestion ;-)