# CustomElements not working in Firefox with about:config properties enabled

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

[CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements) says that `webcomponents` v1 is enabled in Firefox v. 61 with the `about:config` properties `dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled` and `dom.webcomponents.shadowdom.enabled` set to true. And many posts and articles on the web agree with that.

So I have Firefox version 61.0.2 with the aforementioned properties set, and I have a custom element defined as shown below. This renders as expected in Chrome, but in Firefox there is simply nothing rendered and no errors on the console.

```xml
<template id="t">
   ...html content
</template>

<script>
    let template = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#t');

      class MyElement extends HTMLElement {

        constructor() {
          super();
          this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
          this.shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        }
      }
      customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
</script>
```

In case it matters, I'm trying to use the custom element in a separate html file to which I've imported the file which contains the code above.

I understand there is a polyfill I can use, but it's not available in the environment where my app will run. I must be missing something, as everything I read online seems to indicate that Firefox should be able to render the element as I've defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to use the custom element in a separate html file which I'v imported

I suppose then that you use the [HTML Imports](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/) feature that is not implemented in Firefox.

Therefore you'll need to use a polyfill for that: the **file html-imports.min.js** that you can find on the [polyfill github's repository](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports).

```
<script src="html-imports.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="your-custom-element.html">
```

Alternately (if you don't want to use the HTML Imports), put the code of your custom element in a Javascript file:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadow.innerHTML = `...html content`;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realize that FF doesn't support rel links, and that was definitely the problem. Since I can't use polyfills in the deploy environment, I imported a js file as you suggested, and moved the template and style elements to the main html file.

Comment: note that if you dont want to put the template in the main document you can load it with `fetch` of `XMLHttpRequest`