# Web Components, HTML Imports polyfills not working in Firefox, IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, web-component, polyfills, html-imports

I am trying to get Web Components plus HTML Imports to work in Firefox and IE.

I followed the instructions as per [the Web Components GitHub repo](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs), installed the files via npm, and included it towards the head of my document.

I have a custom script that is called in the body of the document.

In firefox, the polyfill is loaded dynamically (synchronously) but transforms the script tag in the body from:

```
<script type="module" src="./src/scripts/init.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>require(["./src/scripts/init.js"]);</script>
```

and I get the following error:
`ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I also tried following [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738748/html-import-webcomponents-polyfill-not-working-in-firefox) and downloaded the polyfills separately:

- [Web Components polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/master/webcomponents-loader.js)
- [Custom Elements Polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements/blob/master/src/custom-elements.js)
- [HTML Imports Polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports/blob/master/html-imports.min.js) for safe measure

(side note: is it advisable to copy/paste the raw code from a repo file? I don't know another way of doing this. I also find it very confusing actually *locating* the proper file as sometimes the file is located in the root folder, other times in 'src'. Am I missing something?)

I sequence the files in `head` like so:

```
<!-- <script src="src/scripts/helper/web-components-polyfill.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/scripts/helper/html-imports-polyfill.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/scripts/helper/custom-element-polyfill.js"></script>
```

*Note: I comment out the "general" web components polyfill as I'm trying to follow the advice of the reference question.*

In Firefox and IE, I get the same error: `require is not defined`. I get this extra goodness in Firefox:
[image: Firefox hell]

I also tried using feature detection to load the polyfills as per [WebComponents.org](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
         if ('registerElement' in document
            && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
            && 'content' in document.createElement('template')) {
            // platform is good!
         } else {
            // polyfill the platform!
            console.log('loading the polyfills');
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = "text/javascript";
            e.src = './src/scripts/helper/html-imports-polyfill.js';
            document.head.appendChild(e);
            var f = document.createElement('script');
            f.src = './src/scripts/helper/custom-elements-polyfill.js';
            document.head.appendChild(f);
         }
      })();
   </script>
```

Again, I get a similar set of errors:
[image: More Firefox hellfire]

The script that launches the app, `init.js`, which I call after the polyfills are "loaded", is set up to import HTML fragments and append them to the document. Here is the function I use for doing that:

```
   /**
     * Dynamically imports HTML into the Main file
     *
     * @param  {String} path The path to the document to import
     * @return {[type]}     [description]
     */
    function _importHTML(path) {
        console.log('importHTML called', path);

        let link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'import';
        link.href = path;

        link.onload = (e) => {
            // console.log('Successfully loaded', e.target.href);
        }

        link.onerror = (e) => {
            console.log('Error loading', e.target.href);
        }

        document.head.appendChild(link);

    }
```

It goes without saying, but everything works fine in Chrome.

Please help! :D

Comment: Have you updated the latest patches for IE and firefox ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The goal is to define code that will work in most browsers so I won't have the luxury of updating other people's browsers. Am I understanding your comment correctly?

Comment: yes you are right. What I wanted to ask is if the browser patches were never updated on the machine then it will create a problem.

Comment: I have faced the similar problem in angular framework. there is a file called "polyfills.ts". I updated the file like following `/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills.**/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set'; `

Comment: I'm not sure if they were ever updated. I am using IE11 and Firefox 60+. I'm not sure how to update the patches but I will look into it. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Please note that HTML imports have been dropped in the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Custom Elements v1 work with Firefox and Edge, you just have to load the **webcomponents-bundle.js** file from the [Web Components polyfill repository](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs).

```
<script src="/your_path/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
```

To make HTML Imports work with Firefox, IE and Edge, you just have to load the **html-imports.min.js** file from [HTML Imports polyfill repository](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports).

```
<script src="/your_path/html-imports.min.js"></script>
```

To get the polyfills you can, on **github**, either :

- download a file directly (right-click on the link then save the file),
- copy/paste the raw content,
- use the green button [Clone of Download] to clone the repository with GIT or download the repository as a ZIP file.

---

Using a polyfill with Internet Explorer to create a Custom Element v1 is more complicated because classes don't exist in Internet Explorer and cannot be fully 
 polyfilled themselves.

However, it is possible to create Custom Elements v0 in Internet Explorer with a polyfill, but it's not recommended.

If you want to use Custom Elements then forget IE :-)

Comment: thanks for answering my questions. I added both the scripts as you advised but in firefox I get the following warnings and errors: `Warning: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8081/src/scripts/helper/bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce.js”.
Warning: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/requirejs/require.js”.
Error: ReferenceError: require is not defined`.` 
This could be due to some cross-scripting error using localhost, as the connection is not secure. I can post this as its own question, too. Thanks

Comment: @Peak where does require.js come from? do you use a some precompiler engine?

Comment: I just noticed a script tag I had in the body with the `type="module"` attr. When the script was active, the `webcomponents-loader.js` would rewrite the script tag in the body (in Firefox) from: `<script type="module" src="./src/scripts/init.js"></script>` to `<script src="/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>require(["./src/scripts/init.js"]);</script>`.

When I remove the `type="module"` or use the `nomodule` attr, that removes the error but I get another reference error coming from the init script: `Define is not defined`. The init script uses es6 including imports.

Comment: I just swapped out my es6 version init script for a transpiled-to-es5 script and that removed the error.